# What happened with this batch script where I got an error, where I can't find anything on the internet about it?

Tags: batch-file

I'm new to Batch, and therefore used an AI to generate a portion of my script, then modified it. I'm encountering an error where it says "2 - Invalid alias verb.". Thanks in advance for the help. The script is not fully finished, and therefore isn't fully feature complete.

Here is the full admin cmd session:

```
This script will update Windows immediately if you press Y.

To cancel, press any other key.
y
Updating Windows cancelled.
2 - Invalid alias verb.
```

Here is the full source code:

```
@echo off

REM Check if running with administrative privileges
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM If not running with administrative privileges, restart script with elevation
if not %errorlevel%==0 (
    echo Running without administrative privileges.
    echo Script needs to be run as an administrator to perform certain operations.
    echo Restarting with administrative privileges...
    echo.
    pause
    powershell.exe -Command "Start-Process -FilePath '%0' -Verb RunAs"
    exit /b
)

REM Prompt user to confirm that they want to update Windows
echo.
echo This script will update Windows immediately if you press Y.
echo.
echo To cancel, press any other key.

set /p "confirm= "

if not "%confirm%"=="Y" (
    echo Updating Windows cancelled.
)


REM Check if the computer is connected to the internet
rem Get the network connection name
set "networkConnection=wmic nic where NetConnectionStatus='2' get Name"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('%networkConnection%') do set networkConnection=%%a

rem Check if the network connection is connected
if "%networkConnection%"=="" (
    echo The computer is not connected to the internet.
    exit /b
)

REM Update Windows
powershell.exe -Command "Get-WindowsUpdate -MicrosoftUpdate | Install-WindowsUpdate -Verbose"

REM Restart the computer
echo.
echo Windows update completed.
echo.
echo The computer will now restart.
echo.
powershell.exe -Command "UsoClient RestartDevice"
```

I have tried Bing and have not found anything relevant. As previously stated, I am new, so I have no clue where to start with what's wrong with the code, even though I have looked thoroughly through the code.

Comment: Your script says the update was canceled, but it doesn't actual cancel the update.  You should use `exit` in that block.

Comment: It looks like it is seeing the `2` where you want it to see the verb `get`.  I suggest you remove the quotes, changing `'2'` to just `2`.

Comment: If you remove @echo off, you can have a rough idea where the error is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

```
set "networkConnection=wmic nic where NetConnectionStatus='2' get Name"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('%networkConnection%') do set networkConnection=%%a
```

should be

```
set "networkConnection=wmic nic where NetConnectionStatus="2" get Name"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('%networkConnection%') do set networkConnection=%%a
```

- using single quotes means that `for /f` sees the command to be executed is terminated at `wmic nic where NetConnectionStatus=` (the second single quote)

It's better to use the `choice` command instead of `set /p` since the string entered for `set /p` is uncontrolled and may include such items as spaces, unbalanced quotes and symbols which are meaningful to batch. (search for `[batch] menu` inn the SO search bar for more)

Regardless, your existing code would probably appreciate

```
if /I not "%confirm%"=="Y" (
    echo Updating Windows cancelled.
    GOTO :EOF
)
```

The `IF` statement can accept the `/i` switch (before the `NOT` - if used) to make the string-comparison case-insensitive.

The `GOTO` will jump to the end if the entry is not `y` or `Y`. As it is, the cancellation message is shown and then the rest of the code is executed regardless.